# How to determine if Julia object is callable

Tags: julia, callable-object

In Julia, what's the best way to determine whether an object is callable?  (E.g. is there an analog of python's `callable` function?)

EDIT: Here's what one could wish for:

```
f() = println("Hi")
x = [1,2,3]
a = 'A'

callable(f)    # => true
callable(x)    # => false
callable(a)    # => false
callable(sin)  # => true
```

Comment: are you looking for `method_exists`?

Comment: @Gnimuc I just tried that, but it doesn't have quite the functionality I'm looking for.  I edited the post to show what I would like (essentially something like Python's `callable`), but perhaps such a feature does not exist (yet) in Julia...

Comment: there is a `Function` type in julia, `typeof(x) <: Function` works well with your examples.

Comment: @Gnimuc That seems like a pretty good solution, and will work for the use case I have in mind.  I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.  (However, I don't think it works generically, since any object can potentially be callable (not just function types).  For example, constructors apparently fail this test of callability.)

Comment: good point. I also hope someone could elaborate more on this topic.

Answer (score 5):

`iscallable(f) = !isempty(methods(f))`

This is the method used in Base (see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/55f44179b9f9c75f8587c19f62cc17f031f5e3fd/base/replutil.jl#L317)).

But consider rethinking your problem. Custom dispatch like this will probably be slow.

Comment: `x = [1]; (x::Vector{T}){T}() = x; x(); iscallable(x)`.  Does just 
`iscallable(f) = !isempty(methods(f))` work?

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders, as of julia 1.8,  `iscallable(f) = !isempty(methods(f))` works with `y = [1]; (y::Vector{T})() where {T} = y; y(); iscallable(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
julia> function iscallable(f)
       try
           f()
           return true

       catch MethodError
           return false
       end
end
iscallable (generic function with 1 method)


julia> f() = 3
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> iscallable(f)
true

julia> x = [1,2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> iscallable(x)
false
```

This is actually quite a Pythonic thing to do (and I suspect not very efficient).
What's the use case?

Comment: `f(x) = 3`, `iscallable(f) => false`.

Comment: This solution is not great, both for the reason @IsaiahNorton mentions (doesn't handle methods with parameters) and because it calls the function if it does exist.